# Finding text between asterisks results in #value

Tags: excel, wildcard

i have a text in a column that looks like the following.

123*abc456*5816

I want my formula to return abc456

Here is the formula I am using.

```
=MID(U3,(SEARCH("~*",U3)+1),((SEARCH("~*",U3)-(SEARCH("~*",U3)+1))))
```

I switched the asterisks to parenthesis to make sure the formula worked and did.  The issue is the file can't be changed so I need to looks for the asterisks.

Comment: Why are you searching for `~`??

Comment: The problem is you are returning the same number in `((SEARCH("~*",U3)-(SEARCH("~*",U3)+1))` so it is returning 1.

Comment: Excel reads * as a wildcard character so to make it not read it as a wild card character I placed a ~(tilde) in front of it so it reads it as an asterisk and not a wildcard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
=MID(A13,FIND("*",A13)+1,FIND("*",A13,FIND("*",A13)+1)-FIND("*",A13)-1)
```

I used cell `A13`.

Edit per Scott comment:
The second `find` is to find the second `*` after you find the first `*`.

Edit2 per Scott comment:
Because you can search for [wildcards](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-SEARCHB-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495) in `search`.

> You can use the wildcard characters — the question mark (?) and
>   asterisk (*) — in the find_text argument. A question mark matches any
>   single character; an asterisk matches any sequence of characters. If
>   you want to find an actual question mark or asterisk, type a tilde (~)
>   before the character.

[image]

Comment: Just for giggles here is the SEARCH() version: `=MID(U3,SEARCH("~*",U3)+1,SEARCH("~*",U3,SEARCH("~*",U3)+1)-(SEARCH("~*",U3)+1))`

Comment: @ScottCraner any more questions =P

Comment: Just trying to make you stretch a little. :)

Comment: @ScottCraner at least you didn't ask me why the sky is blue.

Comment: Why would I ask that, I already know that answer, it is because our atmosphere is mainly nitrogen, and nitrogen vibrates at the right oscillation to disperse the blue light.

Comment: @ScottCraner lol so you mean to tell me you didn't know what the second `find` is for or why you needed `~` for `search`? =PPP

Comment: I was trying to make you look good.  Like any good wingman.  Then you asked one of my favorite questions to ask recent college grads.  The other two: `Why is it warmer in the summer?` and `Why do astronauts seem to float when in the international space station?`

Comment: @ScottCraner `Like any good wingman` lololol uhhh pretty sure you got that backwards. Edit: I don't even qualify to be _your_ wingman. Perhaps some `schlub` =P

Answer (score 2):

I know this has already been answered, but I wanted to provide an alternate solution using the [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332):

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"*",REPT(" ",999)),999,999))
```